# Procedure to generate 2-dimensional convex polytopes with a given number of vertices

Tags: algorithms, polytopes

I need to deal with the following.
Let $[B]$ denote the set of integers $\{0,1,\ldots,B\}$.

> Consider an integer $n \geq 3$ and a grid $[B]\times [B]$, and let $P_{n,B}$ denote the set of convex polytopes in $[B]\times [B]$ of $n$ vertices. How do we sample a uniform element in $P_{n,B}$?

In other words, I need an *algorithmic* to uniquely generate all the convex polytopes of a given number of vertices.

For instance, if $n=3$, then we can simply sample *any* three different points in $[B]\times[B]$, since they automatically define a convex polytope of three vertices.
However, for $n>3$ this does not work since $n$ points may not define a convex polytope.

I assumed this problem has been studied before. Anyone has some insights?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you've considered rejection sampling? Pick any $n$ distinct points, take their convex hull, accept it if it has $n$ vertices, otherwise try again. Note that you'll have to do this even when $n=3$, since the points may be collinear.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks Rahul. Definitely, that's our standard approach, but it scales very badly since, when you increase $n$, the probability of getting a convex hull with a large number of nodes (relatively close to $n$) goes down rather quickly. (Thanks for pointing out the issue with $n=3$ :-) )

Comment: Have you searched some of these links? https://www.google.com/search?q=random+convex+polygon&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 ? The requirement for grid points might be the stumbling block.